# Error compiling Boost.Log

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, boost-log

I am trying to compile the boost log library and I keep getting this error from the `dump_avx2.cpp` file

```
error: always_inline function '_mm256_set1_epi32' requires target feature 'sse4.2', but would be inlined into function 'dump_data_avx2' that is compiled without support for 'sse4.2'
boost/boost/libs/log/src/dump_avx2.cpp:71:31: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_LOG_AUX_MM_CONSTANTS'
    const __m256i mm_char_0 = _mm256_set1_epi32(0x30303030);\
                              ^
```

I get a lot of errors that are very similar to the one above, all of them have the same error message but different locations in the file where they occur,  for reference I am on the commit hash `68701167a1020b0b4c47b76e31d3a3da9e2faf3f` for the Boost.Log submodule as fetched from the github repo (https://github.com/boostorg/boost)

Does anyone know how I can go about resolving this issue?  I am building with a C++14 compiler and this is what I get when I type `g++ --version`

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
```

Thanks!

**Note** I should clarify that in this context it is required that I compile this library separately.

**Note** There seem to be two related source files `dump_ssse3.cpp` and the mentioned `dump_avx2.cpp` file, do I have to compile only one of them?  I cannot make out what to do from the Jamfile in the `build` folder :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug in clang (LLVM). First, the intrinsic belongs to AVX2, not SSE4.2. Second, the whole `dump_avx2.cpp` file is compiled with -mavx2, so the required extensions are enabled. You can see the compiler switches in the error message from b2. And no, both `dump_ssse3.cpp` and `dump_avx2.cpp` should be compiled. The library does runtime detection of the available instructions in the CPU and selects the proper implementation.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I follow what you said :( what is the resolution to the problem of things not compiling?

Comment: Report the problem to the compiler devs. There is no resolution on the library side unless you want to modify it. If you do, you should modify `libs/log/build/Jamfile.v2` file, the `avx2-targets-cond` rule. Comment or remove its contents except the first and the last lines (i.e. the rule should return `<build>no`). That will exclude the AVX2 part of the library from building.

Comment: One last thing, so if I build the library without the `dump_avx2.cpp` file, then will it work as normal without any side effects?

Comment: Yes, the functionality will be unaffected. You'll only lose some performance of the `dump` manipulator.